# Parsing cloudtrail events in s3 bucket

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto3

I have enabled cloudtrail logging in s3 bucket. I am trying to use python sdk in order to parse all the logs in s3 bucket in order to isolate the RunInstance event. I have started with something like this :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('eservice-aws-logging')
    S3KeyPrefix='AWSLogs/********/CloudTrail/us-east-1/',
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
```

Is there a method in Python I can use in order to parse the logs and capture RunInstance events?

Comment: What problem do you want to solve? Is it to find these events once or periodically? If it's once then I recommend [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/). You can download all your CloudTrail logs for one day and then run `zcat *.gz | jq '.Records[] | select(.eventName == "RunInstance")'` in a nice one-liner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the content with

```
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
     if S3KeyPrefix in obj.key:
         content = obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

Once you have the content, parse it for the required events.